# Многопоточность в G++

Tags: многопоточность, gcc

Подскажите, кто с GNU хорошо знаком... есть простая консольная многопоточная программа, которая нормально компилируется и работает на VC++. Используется C++11, обычный `thread`, `mutex`.

Есть машина с redhat, кажется, есть g++, который про себя говорит

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
```

Вопрос - надо запустить на счет на этой машине. Компиляция с `--std=c++11` проходит, но при запуске получаю

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted
```

Подскажите, какие именно ключики нужно передать при компиляции, чтоб все заработало.

На всякий случай - с Linux/GNU и т.п. у меня полная взаимная ненависть :) - за последние лет уже 25 пытался разобраться не раз, но каждый раз через месяц с матами сносил с машины и начинал нормально работать. Поэтому просьба просто указать, что нужно попробовать передать в командной строке, без рекламы Linux. Не моё.

Тем более недопустимы советы что-то переустановить/добавить/изменить. Машина не моя, особого доступа к ней не имею, тем более права что-то менять.

Comment: Не [оно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-are-the-correct-link-options-to-use-stdthread-in-gcc-under-linux)? `$ g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -pthread`

Comment: @MBo Спасибо, попустило! :) Дайте как ответ, чтоб я принял. P.S. Почему без этого не работает? с чем оно тогда линкует?... 8-/

Comment: Увы, не знаю.Встречал нечто подобное - необходимость явного указания по использованию POSIX threads - возможно, в описании fftw (хотя применял Win вариант)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации `std::thread` в Linux используется `pthread`, так что нужно добавить ключ компилятора `-pthread`

Как отмечено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-are-the-correct-link-options-to-use-stdthread-in-gcc-under-linux), это опция линкера, и указывается после исходного файла:

```
 $ g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -pthread
```